# Inserting BSON Document into Collection (C#)

Tags: c#, mongodb

I am trying to insert a BSON document into a Mongo collection.

> MongoDB.Driver.MongoCommandException: 'Command insert failed: error parsing 
>       element 0 of field documents :: caused by :: wrong type for '0' field, 
>       expected object, found 0: [ { Constituency: "Aberdeen North", Election: "2010 
>       General Election", Electorate: 64808, Majority: 8361, ResultOfElection: "Lab 
>       Hold", Turnout: 37701, TurnoutPercentage: 100.0 } ].'

Below is my code.

```
    public void retrieveElectionResuts(string url)
    {
        var client = new RestClient(url);
        var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
        request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");

        IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
        var con = response.Content;

        //Cleaning JSON format
        RootObject result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(con);
        List<Item> items = result.result.items;
        List<ConstituencyResult> electionResults = new List<ConstituencyResult>();
        MongoContext context = new MongoContext();
        var db = context.connect();
        var collection = db.GetCollection<BsonArray>("constituencyResult");
        foreach (Item item in items)
        {
            ConstituencyResult constituencyResult = new ConstituencyResult
            {
                Constituency = item.constituency.label._value.ToString(),
                Election = item.election.label._value.ToString(),
                Electorate = item.electorate,
                Majority = item.majority,
                ResultOfElection = item.resultOfElection,
                Turnout = item.turnout,
                TurnoutPercentage = ((item.electorate) / (item.turnout)) * 100               
            };


            BsonArray array = new BsonArray();
            array.Add(constituencyResult.ToBsonDocument());
            collection.InsertOne(array);


        }
    }
```

I have tried adding the document directly (ie, not putting it in a BSON Array), but this still throws errors.

Answer (score 0):

You can not add `BsonArray` to a collection, because MongoDB document is a set of keys with associated values. When you add array, what should be the key?

You could of course have a field that holds an array. It could be added in the following way:

```
var collection = database.GetCollection<Object>("constituencyResult");
collection.InsertOne(new
{
    SomeArray = array
});
```

In this case document will have `SomeArray` field that will hold array data.

> I have tried adding the document directly (ie, not putting it in a
>   BSON Array), but this still throws errors.

If proposed answer is not what you need  and you get exceptions when adding `ConstituencyResult` objects to the collection, please update your question with definition of `ConstituencyResult` and exception that you get.